# Remove number , punctuation and stem using CountVectorizer in python

Tags: python, text-mining, stemming

I am trying to clean corpus by using CountVectorizer in python. I have written below code, but think tokenize and stem_tokens function is not working as I am not getting required feature some special character gets inserted into features.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import sklearn
import pickle
import os
import string
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text
import pandas
import nltk
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

data = pd.read_csv("Data.csv",encoding='cp1252')
description = data[['Description','Group']]

#splitting data sets into train and test using Sklearn
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(description.Description, description.Group, random_state=1)  

stemmer = PorterStemmer()

def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer):
    stemmed = []
    for item in tokens:
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item))
    return stemmed

def tokenize(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    tokens = [i for i in tokens if i not in string.punctuation]
    stems = stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer)
    return stems

##vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words='english',lowercase=True, ngram_range=(1,2))
vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english',lowercase=True, ngram_range=(1,2))    
train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train.astype('U'))
test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test.astype('U'))
```

Is it because I am using ngram_range=(1,2). 
Can anyone help me to know how can I remove number, punctuation and stem word using CountVectorizer in Python.

Please advice.

Comment: Can you give example of what type of character exist in features?

Comment: Please see below sample of features when I use tokenize and stem_token function ''
'' ''
'' **chang
'' ``
'' al
'' apllic
'' contract
'' dev
'' error
'' ga
'' intern
' mr   
**pleas amend   
â€“ attempt
 It seems feature gets inserted with ",', * , â€“ and @ type of

Comment: I didn't see it. So is it you expected `abc` as feature and got `abc;` as feature or you have ';' in feature for 1-gram?

Comment: I just inserted kind of feature which I am getting , missed to insert example earlier post

Comment: ok let me get this correct. So you expect `chang` but got `**chang`?

Comment: In earlier dtm numbers were available before change , it seems those were replaced with special characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151791/discussion-between-open-source-and-user3734568).